# Clearing value on input not working when two classes present

Tags: javascript

Ok im using this code to clear the inputs, it works great!! as long as the input dont have two classes...

This is working

```
<input class="textBox" name="textBox" value="some value" >

$(document).ready(function() {
    var default_val = '';
    $('input[class^="textBox"]').focus(function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).data('default_val') || !$(this).data('default_val')) {
            $(this).data('default_val', $(this).val());
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    $('input[class^="textBox"]').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).data('default_val'));
    });
});
```

This is not working

But if the input changes to this

```
<input class="text_box textBox" name="textBox" value="some value" >
```

This is not working even if i change my code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var default_val = '';
    $('input[class^="text_box textBox"]').focus(function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).data('default_val') || !$(this).data('default_val')) {
            $(this).data('default_val', $(this).val());
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    $('input[class^="text_box textBox"]').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).data('default_val'));
    });
});
```

This is the input where its not working

```
<input class="text_box textBox" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Su Correo electrónico" size="22">
```

Comment: As for me it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/mCRqJ/

Comment: Just a word of advice, you should be caching your jQuery-wrapped objects so you don't have jQuery doing it over and over. For example, `var $this = $(this)` and then `$this.val('')` and `var $tb = $('input.textBox')` as F.J.'s example puts it.

Comment: BTW, have you considered using the HTML5 placeholder attribute? http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var default_val = '';
    $('input.textBox').focus(function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).data('default_val') || !$(this).data('default_val')) {
            $(this).data('default_val', $(this).val());
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    $('input.textBox').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).data('default_val'));
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried using your code no luck :( i copy & paste the input at the end of my question, the input where this is not working thanks.

Comment: It still works with the input you gave: http://jsfiddle.net/lpiepiora/mCRqJ/1/ - what browser and version are you running it on?

Comment: im using chrome on Mac. =( this is a problem , i cant realize why are there not working.. .. iput the code in a js file loading in the header... it works with one input... but for the other ones is not working... can i sent you a link via PM

Comment: And also not javascript error is displayed in the console :( damn

Comment: YES!!! the problem is that im loading this on header, if i insert this code just after the input.. works like charm,